# Image next to text in ASP.NET View

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to display some text next to an Image I have, however no matter how I change the css it does not seem to respond. In de css file I tried changing "p.StoryLineText" to Just StoryLineText, to just p, I tried p .StoryLine text. Am I missing something obvious?

My view code

```
@model BlueRateITLogicLayer.Models.Film
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Film";
}

<link href="~/Content/FilmsStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <img src="@Model.ImageFilePath" class="FilmImage" />
    <p class="StoryLineText">@Model.StoryLine</p>
    <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

my css file

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

.FilmImage {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}

p.StoryLineText {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: simply add this class and try again .StoryLineText {
    float: right; width: 20px;
}

Comment: seems ok with your existing code (i made a small addition to make the model name go to the next line, but that's it): https://jsfiddle.net/xvbd799v/. Perhaps something else elsewhere in your CSS is interfering. You can use your browser's dev tools to inspect the relevant elements and see what CSS rules are applied to them, and where those rules come from.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work, @Ravikumar

Comment: @ADyson What exactly does the Clear:both do? in your example you have two </div>'s and only one <div> btw is this a typo?

Comment: `clear:both` clears the floats, so the rest of the subsequent markup goes back into the standard layout. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear . MDN documentation is the web developer's best friend, along with the browser Dev tools (Chrome has the best ones, IMHO). Yeah the extra div was a typo, did it quickly, sorry. https://jsfiddle.net/xvbd799v/1/ fixes it with no change to the end result.

Comment: @ADyson It did not seem to help but looking at the source (https://gyazo.com/9b9ba7a186178d9d60bbafa39bd7cfea) it takes the bootstrapper css from the shared layout. I didn't think this would effect it much seeing the p css in the boostrapper is very little. could this be the main cause of the problem?

Comment: Like I said why don't you look in your browser's Dev tools and see if it's interfering or not? You can even use them to switch on and off the properties as you go, to see what effect it has, in real-time. That's the quickest way of diagnosing the problem. It will tell you definitively what rules are applied to the elements and the ones surrounding them. I can't tell anything just by seeing a screenshot of your HTML. Yes it shows that you load Bootstrap, and Site.css and your FilmStyle.css, but that on its own doesn't prove anything. Its the contents of those files and what they do that matters

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference for some guidance on how do inspect the CSS being applied to your HTML.

Comment: @ADyson it would seem that it's still using the bootstrap css rather then using my css file.

Comment: what specifically is bootstrap adding that's overriding what you've specified? Is your CSS even being applied (you should see it in there, but with lines through it, if it was applied but overruled, if it wasn't even applied it just won't be there in the Dev tools)? I'd be surprised if Bootstrap was applying anything conflicting to bog-standard `<img>` and `<p>` tags TBH. Here's the JSfiddle with bootstrap added: https://jsfiddle.net/xvbd799v/2/ . Doesn't seem to have any effect (bootstrap 3.3.7, not sure what version you're using). What's in your Site.css - are you sure it's not from that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a huge fan of floats.

You could use inline-block to stack the elements horizontally.

```
   body {
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    /* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
    .body-content {
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }

    /* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
    input,
    select,
    textarea {
        max-width: 280px;
    }

    .FilmImage {
        width: 150px;
        height: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    p.StoryLineText {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

This will place the text directly to the right of the image and the text will be vertically aligned in the middle of the image.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it does not seem like this solved my problem either.